# Best Practice for SQLAlchemy and Self Referenced Objects

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

There is a self referencing data structure in my model. It can be described as

```
class Example(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'example'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(255))
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('example.id'), nullable=True)
    parent = relationship("Example")
```

I want to create a parent with one or more childs within a session. My first approach was:

1. Create Session
2. Update / Insert Parent (`session.merge`)
3. Commit / Close Session
4. Create new session, load parent, create child
5. set `child.parent_id = parent.id`
6. Commit / Close Session

Since I want to have the whole process as transaction I want to place this in one session.

My Problem if I'm using one session:

Setting `child.parent = parent` results in an TypeError: `ypeError: Incompatible collection type: None is not list-like`. Setting `child.parent_id = parent.id` does not work, because `parent.id` ist not yet set.

Comment: shouldnt parent_id reference a different table's primary key? not the key of it's own table?

Comment: it's a self referring model, which is according to my  understandings, possible

Comment: If you refer to yourself, I don;t believe you need any sort of `relationship` (especially if you dont care if it is nullable)

Comment: if the data is related in a parent-child relationship it should be linked by foreign keys to have triggers that would clean up all children whenever a parent is deleted. ``Null`` would indicate a parent on the toplevel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship() here works in the opposite direction and represents a list of children and not the parent.

It works this way:

```
class Example(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'example'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(255))
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('example.id'), nullable=True)
    children = relationship("Example")
```

And you need then to create parent record and add children to it:

```
    sql = sqldb.get_session()
    child1 = sqldb.system.Example()
    child1.title = 'child-test'
    sql.add(child1)

    child2 = sqldb.system.Example()
    child2.title = 'child-test2'
    sql.add(child2)

    parent = sqldb.system.Example()
    parent.title = 'parent-test'
    parent.children = [child1, child2]
    sql.add(parent)

    sql.commit()
```

Comment: thanks. I should have read the documentation better. I've assumed that I can use it the same way as in Django

Answer (score -1):

```
class Example(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'example'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(255))
    parent_id = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
```

Try something like this, since you are only using one table, you don't need a relationship with yourself.

you should be able do something like

```
ex1 = Example(1,'test')
session.add(ex1)
ex2 = Example(2,'test2',1)
# or ex2 = Example(2,'test2',ex1.id)
session.add(ex2)
```

should work

if you **insist** on having a relationship for various triggers, (which I normally prefer to leave to the responsibility of the programmer, rather than the database for flexibility concerns) use `remote_side`

```
class Example(Base):
    __tablename__ = "example"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(Integer,db.ForeignKey('example.id'))
    children= relationship("Example",
                backref=backref('parent', remote_side=[id])
            )
```

This will create an **adjacency list relationship**
For more information on this please see.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/improve_toc/orm/self_referential.html#adjacency-list-relationships

Comment: In my opinion omitting a relationship should not be considered as best practices, because you are losing the ability to have triggers or constraints in your DBMS. also your solution assumes that I'm keeping track about the primary key over all interactions, which should be done by the DBMS

Comment: Ive updated my answer. Normally, I leave such constraints you are referencing up to the individual applications communicating with the database. for example, I have 3 applications, using a single database, but they all have different constraints for their use cases